# do you need to know ios 7 if you want to program for ios 8?

Tags: ios, iphone

Not really a programming question, but this topic needs an up to date discussion for all the newbies outthere. I've googled but didn't find anything useful. So, do you need to know ios 7 if you want to program for ios 8? Is iOS 8 just a extension and everything in programming for iOS 7 is also valid in iOS 8? There are many books on iOS 7(not so much on iOS8), but it would be a waste of money to buy out of date books. 
Thanks for answering

Comment: StackOverflow is not the right place for a discussion.

Comment: any recommended forums?

Comment: iOS 8 slightly differs from iOS 7.

Comment: so basically, the BNR book, although written for iOS7 is a good place to start iOS8 programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### IMO:

you don't really have to know the past of iOS... only when you want to support lower OS versions and even then you only need to know what changed in that area / what you need to change

said that though: it doesn't hurt to have a general foundation. ;) generally :D

Comment: does the general foundation start at iOS7 or do I need to go deeper?:D

Comment: start with 8, if you want to then support 7 look at the deltas between 8 and 7 - supporting earlier oss isn't needed.